# Can two or more threads iterate over the same List<t> without any problems?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Talking about `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` here.

With example below can Method1 and Method2 execute and the same time, on different threads without any problems?

Thanks

```
class Test
{
    private readonly List<MyData> _data;

    public Test()
    {
        _data = LoadData();
    }

    private List<MyData> LoadData()
    {
        //Get data from dv.
    }

    public void Method1()
    {
        foreach (var list in _data)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }

    public void Method2()
    {
        foreach (var list in _data)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Yes, `List<T>` is safe to *read* from multiple threads so long as no threads are *modifying* the list.

From [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx):

> A `List<T>` can support multiple
>   readers concurrently, as long as the
>   collection is not modified.
>   Enumerating through a collection is
>   intrinsically not a thread-safe
>   procedure. In the rare case where an
>   enumeration contends with one or more
>   write accesses, the only way to ensure
>   thread safety is to lock the
>   collection during the entire
>   enumeration. To allow the collection
>   to be accessed by multiple threads for
>   reading and writing, you must
>   implement your own synchronization.

(The point about iterating being "intrinsically not a thread-safe procedure" is made in respect of something else mutating the list.)

Comment: If the list changes, when you want to iterate it, you can make a copy of it and iterate its copy, I don't use that practice, but I think it can be useful

Answer (score 0):

You can use the iterators gotten by the foreach() just fine on multiple threads. As long as you don't add or remove elemnts from the list, you should be fine. I believe that you even get to modify the members of whatever your  is, but this takes you into non-thread-safe territory.